How to maka a subdivided torus with a square shaped cross-section?
I am trying to create the shape shown on the picture in 3D (a torus wall with a square-shaped cross section, spaces in-between). I can make it with the >spin cube< tool but it leaves me with edges I cannot cut out in a straight line. Is there a way to cubify a torus' edges to get this shape?


The following solution with Geometry Nodes might be a bit over the top, but it leaves you with more or less full adjustability, so perhaps it is interesting to you:
In this nodetree, I use a Curve Circle node with a Quadrilateral as Profile Curve in a Curve to Mesh node to create the basic torus with a square cross section. This torus I plug into the Mesh 1 input of a Mesh Boolean node set to Difference.
Then I use a Cube object or actually a cuboid wide enough on X to exceed the torus. This original cuboid and a second version of it rotated by 90° on Z are both plugged into the Mesh 2 input of the Mesh Boolean. These will create the gaps in the torus wall.
I use inputs on the Group Input node for the different parameters, Resolution and Radius of the circle, then the Torus Profile Width, the Gap Width for the cutouts and last but not least a switch to decide if the torus profile should be square and if not, it uses the Optional Profile Height.
To make sure the cuboids cutting the gaps are always wide and high enough, I calculate the necessary X dimension of the cuboid by 2 × Radius + Profile Width in a Math node set to Multiply Add. A Switch node is used to toggle the profile's Z height between profile width for square profiles and optional height for non-square profiles. These X and Z values are plugged into a Combine XYZ node together with the Gap Width as Y value.
I then multiply the resulting Vector output by 1.2 on X and Z to make the cutting objects large enough to exceed the torus, the Y value only gets multiplied by 1 because I do not want to change the width of the gaps.

And this is how you can change the appearance by adjusting the values, the overall size by changing the Radius:

Or the "thickness" of the torus walls by adjusting the Torus Profile Width, here with a square profile so width and height are changing together:

Or if you want to control the height individually, disabling Square Profile and adjusting the Optional Profile Height:

And of course the width of the cutouts can be changed as well with Gap Width:

These are just a few adjustments for the basic object in the question, four torus segments with a square or rectangular cross section. Sure there can be made many additions or variations of this.


⬆ ShiftA Add a torus with Major Segments divisible by $4$, so that there are two perpendicular [see GIF below] loops that overlap axes; select them, make sure you switch to 1 Vertex Selection Mode, H hide them, hover your mouse over the bigger part of the torus, L Select Connected, X Delete Vertices. ⎇ AltH reveal hidden loops:

You may want to fill the holes, either just be ⎇ Alt-clicking the boundary and then F to fill with an n-gon [on the right below] or by F3 searching for "Grid Fill":

⬆ ShiftA Add an Empty in the center, and on the torus-quarter add the Array modifier, using this Empty as an Object Offset:

In Edit Mode move the the geometry away from the origin to create spacing:

Edit: You wanted a cube profile so try Minor Segments = 4, and if you want the top looking up, then start with a default Plane, ⭾ Tab (It's important to edit in Edit Mode), RX90↩ EnterGX3 and add a Screw modifier.

Thank you, however the one you created still has a circular cross-section. I would like to have something like a bent cube.
Also I would like to keep the perfect circle, not like on the last picture as it distorts it to a sqaure.

@Silvia maybe Minor Segments = 4 will satisfy you? or do you want the top face looking up

If I look at the reference, there you have a circular shape with basically a cross-shaped cutout, where the segments are not full 90° arcs. In your example you have the torus separated in 90° arcs and move them apart from each other to have gaps between them - resulting not in a circular shape, but a square with rounded corners.

@GordonBrinkmann ahhh, fair.
